# Почему вместо отрендеренного содержимого выводится код шаблона blade?

Tags: php, laravel

Версия Laravel 5.2.36. Homestead не использую.

Файл `test.blade.php`

```
@extends('app')
@section('asd')
asd
@stop
```

Файл app.blade.php

```
@yield('asd')
```

Контроллер

```
public function index() {
    return view('test.test')
}
```

При просмотре страницы ожидаю увидеть:

> asd

А вижу вывод кода шаблона:

> @extends('app')
>   @section('asd')
>   asd
>   @stop

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Покажите что именно выводится и что вы ожидаете увидеть

Comment: Выводится @extends('app') Ожидаю увидеть шаблон

Comment: Выводится как обычный текст сам код, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Верно. Выводится как обычный текст

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какая версия Laravel у вас прямо в вопросе. Не просто `5`, а с номером минорной версии. Например, `5.1`. А еще версию Homestead, если используете его.

Comment: Версия 5.2.36 Laravel. Homestead не использую.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40875/discussion-between-asd-and-venzell).

Comment: Ну так что скажите? С чем может быть связана эта ошибка?

Comment: В индексной функции ";" не стоит в конце. И попробуйте в консоле php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 2):

Пример контроллера:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function selectViewItem()
    {
       return view('test.index');
    }
```

Пример вызова в route:

```
Route::get('/test','TwitterController@selectViewItem');
```

Это частая проблема. Или вы забыли в роут вызвать или вы снесли сам шаблонизатор.